# Can a single Process / Thread ever cause deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, locks

I was reading concept of deadlock from Galvin and I am getting a doubt that can a single process / thread ever go in deadlock...?
Coz the definition (or as a matter of fact the whole Deadlock chapter in Galvin) doesnt seem to be talking about what if there is a single process / thread in the system..
(Plz tell if I have missed upon any point..while reading it...if yes sincere apology..for my previous statement but I simply could not find it in chapter anywhere..)

Every where Galvin Book uses the word "Other" process while describing deadlock scenario...
So what I feel the answer to my question is No , a single process / thread can never go in deadlock..
(Okay also me: what I feel that a single process in some case may lead to indefinite waiting ..can I call it as a deadlock..?)

To know the motivation why I am bringing Deadlock and Indefinite waiting into one Picture..plz read below scenario
(Okay also plz let me know that whether I am correct in assuming that indefinite waiting is not same as deadlock...i may be wrong..??)
Consider a scenario:
There is one thread (t) and one lock(l).
Lock nature Non re entrant.
(Meaning when thread holds lock l then it cannot acquire it once again before it releases it...I could find only this as definition on internet.)
(One more condition:
If a thread could not acquire lock then it blocks itself untill it gets available...yes it's pretty obvious point but this point is creating mess..plz read below to get insight..)
Now it's claimed that say t acquires a lock l and then does its execution meanwhile it requires the same lock again..(may be because it has to Do some recursive function call...like as in BFS/ DFS...or may be something similar..)
So obviously it has to leave that lock before acquiring that lock...but since process cannot acquire same lock again so it has to wait or simply gets blocked till it becomes available...
Now the important point is ...it would be blocked till it ..itself releases the lock..now my question is can this scenario lead to a deadlock...
(Yes it can release again..and then reacquire...but my problem is not pertaining to this case..)
So my problem is can this case ever lead to deadlock...(like thread waits for itself...)
-->like in worst case type scenario..
(Also whenever a process / thread  goes in blocking state /waiting state does it hold locks/ resources..??plz also shed light here ...)
(I hope what I am talking about is clear...if not plz comment and tell I'll try my best to clarify...yes this point is very delicate where I want to raise doubt)

That scenario is actually an exam problem..whose answer is : Yes a single thread with single lock can lead to deadlock-->which I feel conflicts with deadlock defintion..)
I know I am raising many doubts but the primary problem is same.

Below is key point summary of my doubt:

-single process/ there's in deadlock?

-indefinite wait vs deadlock

-is it necessary for a process/thread to release locks..when goes in blocked/waiting state?

(First of all thanks if you made it till this point...coz it's really a long doubt..I did it just so as to make my point clear...if not comment..I'll make it again..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> single process/ there's in deadlock?

Yes, as you mentioned, if a function in the thread holds a lock and recursively calls itself, then it could lead to a deadlock. If the lock has been implemented to not block, when the already holding thread requests for the lock, then, of course, we won't have the deadlock.

> indefinite wait vs deadlock

No these are not one and the same. A deadlock happens if none of the threads are able to make progress. If one thread (holding the lock) is able to make progress while blocking/delaying other threads indefinitely, that's not a deadlock. Another interesting concept is Livelocks - where threads are not making progress but appear to be "alive"/active.

> is it necessary for a process/thread to release locks..when goes in blocked/waiting state?

No, for example, suppose a thread holds a lock to protect a memory page from being accessed by other threads, and then starts a read from disk into that memory page. This I/O is would most likely suspend the thread, until the transfer from disk completes. This is a legitimate use of hold-the-lock-and-suspend. There are numerous such cases, where threads can block while holding the lock.

Comment: @PiyushSawarkar to expand on the last point in Chandan's excellent post, this is where the concept of priority inversion comes in. Such a thread holding a lock but blocked on I/O might be getting in the way of a higher priority thread that wants the lock for itself. The priority inversion is that the lower priority thread is now getting in the way of a higher priority thread. Some operating systems will resolve priority inversions - their schedulers will do whatever it takes to expedite the lower priority thread until it releases the lock. Linux didn't (still doesn't?) do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write a process that will deadlock. Try taking a semaphore twice... However, such code will deadlock each and every time, and so isn't really a problem as such because such a bug isn't going to escape the notice of even the most inattentive of testers.

**Deadlock as a Problem**

Generally, deadlock is a problem when a multi-threaded program has the potential to deadlock, but will do so only when timings of events are unfortunate (e.g. two threads having to reach certain points in their execution at certain times in order for deadlock to occur). This makes it much, much harder to detect through testing. Avoiding it in such a program requires the developer(s) to have designed their code properly.

For systems using shared memory and semaphores to guard access, proving analytically that the design is free of deadlock is difficult in non-trivial designs.

**Communicating Sequential Processes**

There are methods of asserting that a software design is free of deadlock. Look up Communicating Sequential Processes. This is a process calculi developed by Tony Hoare back in the 1970s, was popular in the 1980s (embodied on the Transputer), and has recently made something of a comeback in languages such as Rust and Go.

The process calculi - the maths - that one can do with a CSP design allows the designer to demonstrate analytically that their design is free of deadlock issues. This has been done in practice; the Wikipedia page cites an e-commerce system that was proved this way.

The practicality of CSP at the codeface is that you have independent processes / threads intercommunicating via "channels", with sending / receiving being synchronous. That is, when two threads exchange messages, the sender is blocked until the receiver has received a message. This is what both Rust and Go have re-introduced, and I can't help but laugh a little at people "discovering" CSP (over 40 years since it was first thought of).

The beauty of this is that it's not obligatory to do the maths to prove a design is free of deadlock. If you write the code in a CSP style, run it, and it doesn't deadlock, then it won't deadlock ever.

CSP is also highly suitable in real time systems; failure to meet the real time performance requirement isn't disguised by latency in network buffers, etc.

This is in stark contrast to the earlier, and related, Actor model. In this, senders and receivers are not synchronised; the sender sends and resumes execution, their message sits in some buffer or queue somewhere or other, and eventually makes it to the receiver. Actor model systems can deadlock (and livelock), and this may happen on that one day when the network infrastructure gets just a little bit more busy than usual.

**Modern Technology**

What one can observe is that the majority of technology that gets used on the Internet follows (one way or other) the Actor model; ip / tcp doesn't provide synchronisation between sender and receiver. And this is fair enough; to achieve synchronisation between processes separated by half a planet takes a lot of to-ing and fro-ing of traffic across networks. Asynchronous is better for the efficient performance of large scale, planet-straddling networks.

This means that, whilst languages like Go and Rust have re-introduced the idea of CSP within a process on a single computer, there aren't many implementations of CSP that straddle computer networks (i.e. CSP on top of TCP/IP). I think Erlang does this.

ZeroMQ gets very, very close to doing that (misses out by a whisker - it has a minimum output buffer size of 1...).

Being something of a fan of CSP I have occasionally implemented custom CSP libraries on top TCP/IP, and it proved extremely useful.

Comment: That's a lot of knowledge!! I'll try my best to understand it..appreciate your efforts ..!

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to follow your post, but let me give some examples

A good lock manager should throw an exception if a thread is requesting an application lock it already has.
You need to have code in your application which records you have the lock, so you can release it in exception or normal termination.

A lock can be a lock object where you say "get unique lock".

Two threads can communicate using wait and post on an ECB/Mutex.
So task1 posts mutex1 and waits on mutex2

task 2 was waiting on mutex 1,  wakes up, does some work, posts mutex1, waits on mutext2

Task 1 wakes up

If you dont have task 2 running, just task 1 then  you get task 1 waiting for a mutex which never gets posted.    This can be considered as a deadlock with just one thread.

---

You can also get "a deadly embrace" where task1 has lock 1, and is waiting for lock 2, and task 2 has lock2 and is waiting for lock 1.

---

Some systems have a lock hierarchy before you get lock2 you need lock 1.

So your code is

```
get lock1
get lock2 
release lock1
...
release lock2
```

this avoids the deadly embrace.

If you are locking rows in a database you can get situations where an update requires multiple locks on data, page, row etc, and get deadlock here - so one task many locks.